# Can you travel to Canada and back to the US using a Nevada REAL ID?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, canada, us-citizens

Can my friend drive from Seattle,  WA to Vancouver, BC and back with a Nevada-issued REAL ID?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No. Driving into Canada is possible with enhanced driver license, but Nevada doesn't issue those. EDL is not the same as Real ID.

Comment: Right. [According to wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enhanced_driver%27s_license), only Michigan, Minnesota, New York, Vermont, and Washington currently issue EDLs and Ohio recently passed a bill to do so, but hasn't started issuing them yet.

Comment: Which happen to be states that border on Canada, with likely a lot of routine cross-border transit on a regular basis.

Answer (score 2):

To enter Canada in the first place, you will need proper documentation of citizenship in the US. That is best proved by having a valid Passport or Passport Card. [cic.gc.ca](https://www.cic.gc.ca/english/helpcentre/answer.asp?qnum=1116&top=16)

If your Nevada-issued Real ID is also a Nevada State Driver's License, and you have proof of insurance, then you should be fine to drive within Canada. [usa.gov](https://www.usa.gov/international-drivers-license#:%7E:text=When%20visiting%20another%20country%20as,(IDP)%20for%20foreign%20drivers.)

The Enhanced Drivers License (EDL) is a program that was intended to provide both proof of citizenship and driving license. Canada has stopped issuing EDLs, and only a handful of states issue EDLs. [dhs.gov](https://www.dhs.gov/enhanced-drivers-licenses-what-are-they) and [ontario.ca](https://www.ontario.ca/page/enhanced-drivers-licence#:%7E:text=The%20Enhanced%20Driver%27s%20Licence%20(%20EDL%20)%20was%20a%20travel%20document%20that,States%20by%20road%20or%20water.)